# Android Listview - setting constraint for specified number of user's selection

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I restrict user from selecting not more than a specified number of items of listview?Also if user deselect the already selected item user should be able to select new one.

Comment: show us your current approach? what did you do until now?

Comment: you can use a flag in your custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter in your adapter class and compare it with the `maximumNoOfItemToSelect` and not allow the user to select if it's greater than `maximumNoOfItemToSelect`

something like this

```
class MyAdapter
{
    int counter=0;
    ...
}
```

when user selects an item

```
counter++;
```

when user deselects an item

```
counter--;
```

before `selection` check this `condition`

```
if (counter > maximumNoOfItemToSelect)
{
//don't select the item
}
```